# It's possible to know the field that holds the focus before button click?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, focus

In a form, that have a couple of text items and a button, it's possible to know in which item the focus was before the click in the button?

I want to open another form, in a button click, and this form have a "context" that depends in the focus of the previous form.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

I tried to hold the last focused element in the controller, binding the `blur` event of all fields, but it seems that this event is not synchronized in IE (always he), Chrome and FF seems ok with that.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    id: 'MyController',
    views: [
        'MyView'
    ],
    init : function(application){
        var me = this;

        me.lastFocus = null;

        me.control({
            '.field' : {
                blur: me.fieldBlur,
                scope: me
            }
        });
    },

    fieldBlur: function(field, event, opts) {
        this.lastFocus = field;
        //console.log('lastFocus: ' + field);
    }

});
```

Comment: It should work in [all major browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html) but I recommend you to use this selector `[isFormField]` you may also see may edit. I will also add some info how the FocusManager is gatering the focus/blur information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried it myself but **[Ext.FocusManager.focusedCmp](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.FocusManager-property-focusedCmp)** looks promising. Note that you will need to activate it before you can use it by calling **[Ext.FocusManager.enable()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.FocusManager-event-enable)**

Edit

I thought it would be more stable by now. I am sorry to hear that it seams not to help you but I can not understand why the `focusedCmp` should be `undefined` on time you are clicking the button it should be the button. And with that I come to my error you need to access `previousFocusedCmp`.

But it should work cause what it does it no magic...

A little example **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YrpCe/)**:

```
Ext.FocusManager.enable();
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Form',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    width: 350,

    // The form will submit an AJAX request to this URL when submitted
    url: 'save-form.php',

    // Fields will be arranged vertically, stretched to full width
    layout: 'anchor',
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },

    // The fields
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'first',
        allowBlank: false
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        name: 'last',
        allowBlank: false
    }],

    // Reset and Submit buttons
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function() {
            console.log('Most likely the button you clicked: ', Ext.FocusManager.focusedCmp, 'The Component that was focused before:  ',Ext.FocusManager.previousFocusedCmp );
            this.up('form').getForm().reset();
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Submit',
        formBind: true, //only enabled once the form is valid
        disabled: true,
        handler: function() {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if (form.isValid()) {
                form.submit({
                    success: function(form, action) {
                       Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
                    },
                    failure: function(form, action) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result.msg);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

> **How does the FocusManger do it in one sentence (we spare the keynav):**
>
> Well as soon as he get's enabled he queries the whole DOM for all
>   focusable components and tell each of them to inform him about focus and blur
>   changes.

Comment: Interesting. For me it returned 'undefined' when I clicked in the button. Also, it messed up with the form navigation.

Comment: Saw your edit and tested here again. It worked only on Chrome. FF get's the button as `previousFocusedCmp` and undefined as `focusedCmp`. IE sometimes get's the correct field and sometimes don't. The navigation is messed up maybe because I have containers inside the form (to align horizontally some fields), so it's trapped to the container, not going to the next.

Comment: It seems that if I delay my button handler I can use the `blur` in IE too. But thanks for sharing `Ext.FocusManager`!

Comment: @SérgioMichels You're welcome :) The IE blur problem is quite interesting... thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

From the persective of a user this sounds a bit shady, but whatever here you go:

use [jQuery mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) on each of the forms and where it sets some global variable to itself or a respective string, when the button is called the variable contains the last active field.

something like

```
var last_active = 0;
function set_last_active(e, ui){
    last_active = $(this);
}
$('.tracked_form').mouseover(set_last_active);
```

should do the trick, also see if you can use [event bubbling](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1751-jQuery-Live-Method-And-Event-Bubbling.htm).

Comment: Hi. Forms can be navigated with tab, so I don't think that mouseover is the answer. Also, I'm using only ExtJS without JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The proposal of using `blur` event in the form fields works in the button if you delay the access to my `lastFocus` attribute.

```
onButtonClick : function(button, e, eOpts) {
  var me = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
      alert(me.lastFocus.getItemId());
  }, 250);
}
```